# Logarithmic y-axis tick color in matplotlib subplots doesn't work

Tags: matplotlib, subplot, logarithm, yaxis

I am plotting a function in matplotlib using subplots (I have to use subplots because of other reasons) and like to set the y-scale to logarithmic while having the y-ticks in the color red.

I used this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_data = np.arange(500.0, 900.0, 1.0)
def func(x):
    return a*(x/500.0)**(-b)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x_data, 10*func(x_data))
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.tick_params('y', colors='r')
plt.show()
```

[image using code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44fU0.png)

The tickcolor is black although I specificly set it to red.
However, when I choose a linear scale, the tickcolor is red:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_data = np.arange(500.0, 900.0, 1.0)
def func(x):
    return a*(x/500.0)**(-b)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x_data, 10*func(x_data))
ax.set_yscale('linear')
ax.tick_params('y', colors='r')
plt.show()
```

[image using code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13zVR.png)

Also, when a manually select the y-axis range, the first tick is red:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_data = np.arange(500.0, 900.0, 1.0)
def func(x):
    return a*(x/500.0)**(-b)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x_data, 10*func(x_data))
ax.set_yscale('linear')
ax.tick_params('y', colors='r')
plt.show()
```

[image using code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRdZ1.png)

It has something to do with the logarithmic scale but I don't know how to solve it. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ticks you see in the first graph are *minor* ticks, and [`ax.tick_params`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html) applies to major ticks by default.

You can specify which ticks `ax.tick_params` applies to using the `which=` argument:

```
ax.tick_params('y', which="both", colors='r')
```

Comment: @Owerkeijer FYI: it is good practice to upvote and/or accept an answer that solves your problem or is helpful.